# How to delete or mask entries of a numpy array relative to another entry

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a Numpy array that looks like this:

```
X = np.array([(1,2,'Bye'), (1,2,'Zero'), (5,7,'One'), (1,2,'Two'), (5,7,'Bye'),
(500,600,'Three'), (12,40,'Four'), (12,40,'Five'), (5,7,'Bye')],
dtype=[('foo','i4'),('bar','i4'),('baz','S10')])
```

I'm trying to create a new array which omits any entry containing `'Bye'`, as well as the entry before and after it.

From what I understand the most efficient way to achieve this is with a masked array, however I've only managed to successfully mask the `'Bye'` entries, not the entries around them:

```
ma.masked_where(X['baz']==b'Bye', X)
```

How can I expand this to also include the entries before and after `'Bye'`? A big problem I have is that sometimes these values overlap, or don't exist (e.g. in the case of the first `'Bye'`.

I have also tried with a bunch of nested `for` and `if` loops with `np.delete()`, but I'd prefer not to go that route.

Comment: Why putting strings in a numpy array? Numpy is designed for numerical stuff... Would be easily done with a regular python list.

Comment: Cheers @JulienBernu, I was using Numpy as I want to do numerical stuff with the numerical values in the arrays later on, while still retaining some of the associated information in the strings for reference later on. Should I still use a Numpy list? And, if so, could you show me how to do that? I had tried using a list previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Data

---

```
In [55]:
X = np.array([(1,2,'Bye'), (1,2,'Zero'), (5,7,'One'), (1,2,'Two'), (5,7,'Bye'),
(500,600,'Three'), (12,40,'Four'), (12,40,'Five'), (5,7,'Bye')])
X
Out[55]:
array([['1', '2', 'Bye'],
       ['1', '2', 'Zero'],
       ['5', '7', 'One'],
       ['1', '2', 'Two'],
       ['5', '7', 'Bye'],
       ['500', '600', 'Three'],
       ['12', '40', 'Four'],
       ['12', '40', 'Five'],
       ['5', '7', 'Bye']], 
      dtype='|S11')
```

### Solution

---

```
# The indeices with `Bye` value   
In [82]:
init_mask_indices = np.where(X[: , 2] == b'Bye')
init_mask_indices
Out[82]:
(array([0, 4, 8], dtype=int64),)

# The indices after rows with `Bye` value
In [81]:
plus_one = init_mask_indices + np.array([1])
plus_one
Out[81]:
array([[1, 5, 9]], dtype=int64)

# The indices before rows with `Bye` value
In [80]:
minus_one = init_mask_indices - np.array([1])
minus_one
Out[80]:
array([[-1,  3,  7]], dtype=int64)

# All indices
In [90]:
arr_all =np.concatenate((init_mask_indices , plus_one , minus_one) , axis = 1)
arr_all
Out[90]:
array([[0,  4,  8,  1,  5,  9, -1,  3,  7]], dtype=int64)

# Final indices
In [96]:
arr_final = np.unique(arr_all[ np.logical_and( arr_all >= 0 , arr_all < len(X)) ]) 
arr_final
Out[96]:
array([0,1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8], dtype=int64)
```

### Mask

---

```
In [102]:
mask = np.array([False]).repeat(len(X))
mask
Out[102]:
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [103]:
mask[arr_final] = True
mask
Out[103]:
array([ True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [104]:
mask
X[mask]
Out[104]:
array([['1', '2', 'Bye'],
       ['1', '2', 'Zero'],
       ['1', '2', 'Two'],
       ['5', '7', 'Bye'],
       ['500', '600', 'Three'],
       ['12', '40', 'Five'],
       ['5', '7', 'Bye']], 
      dtype='|S11')
```

Comment: Great, this worked perfectly, thanks! I edited your answer to switch the `True` and `False` in the mask arrays, as you completed the inverse of what I was looking for! In my own solution I also kept the `dtype` of my numbers as `i4`. Cheers! Would it have been preferable to use a list in this situation, as Julien said, even if I am performing numerical operations on the numbers in my arrays? Thanks!

Comment: calling `np.array` on a list that contains strings automatically converts your numerical values to strings, bad! I suggest processing your python list first (trimming out strings and whichever entries you don't want), see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion, first process your data as python native list, then convert to `np.array`:

```
X = [(1,2,'Bye'), (1,2,'Zero'), (5,7,'One'), (1,2,'Two'), (5,7,'Bye'),
(500,600,'Three'), (12,40,'Four'), (12,40,'Five'), (5,7,'Bye')]

def my_filter(L, k, word):
    if L[k][2] == word:
        return False
    if k > 0 and L[k-1][2] == word:
        return False
    if k < len(L) - 1 and L[k+1][2] == word:
        return False
    return True

filter_indices, filter_X = zip(*[(i,x) for i,x in enumerate(X) if my_filter(X, i, 'Bye')])
np_filter_X = np.array([x[:2] for x in filter_X])
```

Result for `filter_indices` (filtered indices in original unfiltered data):

```
(2, 6)
```

Result for `filter_X`:

```
[(5, 7, 'One'), (12, 40, 'Four')]
```

Result for `np_filter_X`:

```
array([[ 5,  7],
       [12, 40]])
```

Now your `np.array` actually is numerical, and not strings '1', '2', etc...

EDIT: concerning datatype and performance, see this simple example:

```
%timeit np.linalg.matrix_power(1+np.random.rand(100,100), 100)
1000 loops, best of 3: 387 µs per loop
```

now exact same computation but with general object as datatype:

```
%timeit np.linalg.matrix_power(1+np.random.rand(100,100).astype("object"), 100)
10 loops, best of 3: 156 ms per loop
```

400 times slower!

Comment: Thanks, Julien! This also works with the data I have. Would there be an advantage in doing it this way over, using a numpy array, but specifying the data types so that I have integers for the first two entries, and a string for the third (as in my earlier code)?

Comment: `np.array` have only one datatype (`dtype`), the only way to have both strings and numericals would be to set the datatype as general object: `dtype=object`. But then you may loose performance: again numpy is designed and optimised for numerical computing only even if it accepts other types for convenience.